# How can I determine if a variable is an array? [JS NG TS CS JQ]

Tags: javascript, arrays

Sometimes it is necessary to determine what type of data a variable contains, in this specific case we are talking about the `Array` type.

How can I end in the different scenarios if the variable is `Array` type?
I'm talking about scenarios, I'm talking about `jQuery`, `Angular`, `TypeScript`, `CoffeeScript`, etc.

Thank you!

Comment: Use `Array.isArray`. If you need to support browsers without support for this, polyfill it.

Answer (score -2):

There are different forms depending on the library, framework or language to use.

Here it will compile a list of the different ways to verify if the variable is of type `array`.

**jQuery *(since v1.3)***

```
var value = [];
if ($.isArray(value)) {
    console.log('this variable is a array');
}
```

**Angular**

```
$scope.value = [];
if (angular.isArray($scope.value)) {
    console.log('this variable is a array');
}
```

**Angular2**

```
value = [];
if (Array.isArray(value)) {
    console.log('this variable is a array');
}
```

**ECMAScript 5**, **ECMAScript 6** and *TypeScript*

```
var value = [];
if (Array.isArray(value)) {
    console.log('this variable is a array');
}
```

**CoffeeScript**

```
value = []
if {}.toString.call(value) is '[object Array]'
    console.log 'this variable is a array'
```

**CoffeeScript(as function)**

```
Array.isArray || ( value ) -> return {}.toString.call(value) is '[object Array]'
value = []
if Array.isArray(value)
    console.log 'this variable is a array'
```

**Object.prototype**

```
var value = [];
if( Object.prototype.toString.call( value ) === '[object Array]' ) {
    alert( 'Array!' );
}
```

**Pure javascript:**

```
function isArray(value) {
    return !!value && Array == value.constructor;
}

var value = [];
if (isArray(value)) {
    console.log('this variable is a array');
}
```